# Microsoft Flow New Email Trigger is Skipping Some Emails

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that's triggered on each new email in Gmail under a specific label, it worked fine for a long time until two days ago it started skipping some emails.
I noticed that for the few emails that were skipped there was another email received at the exact same time (matching the same rules) and MS Flow only picked up one of the two.

Is there any way I can fix this issue, that it should trigger on both emails even if received at same time?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your power automate flow?

Comment: @SarahCox I added a picture, as you can see there are no filters besides label, and the flow doesn't get triggered at all if there are more than one email coming in at the same time.